# How to hide the Load More button when all posts are displayed

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Implemented dynamic loading of posts using AJAX. The code works and the posts come as they should. Now the problem is that I need to hide the button when all posts have been displayed, but I don't understand how to do it. How can I get the number of posts and pass that to js to hide the button. How can I implement it?

```js
let currentPage = 1;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#load-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentPage++;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        action: 'load_more',
        paged: currentPage,
      },
      success: function(res) {
        $('.news-дist').append(res);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```js
function load_more()
{
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
    ]);

    $response = '';

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($query->post->ID);
            $post_title = get_the_title($query->post_title);
            $post_author = get_the_author($query->post_author);
            $post_date = get_the_date('d F Y');
            $post_permalink = get_permalink($query->post->ID);

            echo '<li>
              <a href="' . $post_permalink . '">
                <div class="latest-news__image">
                <img src="' . $img_url . '" alt="' . $post_title . '">
                </div>
                <h4>' . $post_title . '</h4>
                 <div class="post-credentials">
                 <p class="post-author">By ' . $post_author . '</p>
                 <p class="post-date">' . $post_date . '</p>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </li> ';
        endwhile;
    } else {
        $response = 'empty';
    }

    echo $response;
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870265/wordpress-ajax-hide-load-more-button, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746739/hide-load-more-button-if-there-are-no-posts-left-to-load, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509882/hide-the-button-load-more-when-no-more-posts-are-available, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724723/ajax-load-more-hide-button-if-no-more-content, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724499/wordress-loadmore-ajax-doenst-hide-button, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21407809/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36281357/6089612, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ajax response, you need to pass the max pages in JSON format. Then hide the button if the current page is greater or equal to the max page.

**js:**

```
(function ($) {
  let currentPage = 1;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#load-more").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      currentPage++;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          action: "load_more",
          paged: currentPage,
        },
        success: function (res) {
          if (currentPage >= res.max) {
            $("#load-more").hide();
          }
          $(".news-list").append(res.html);
        },
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Ajax callback:**

```
function load_more()
{
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'paged'          => $_POST['paged'],
    ]);

    $response  = '';
    $max_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            $img_url        = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($query->post->ID);
            $post_title     = get_the_title($query->post_title);
            $post_author    = get_the_author($query->post_author);
            $post_date      = get_the_date('d F Y');
            $post_permalink = get_permalink($query->post->ID);

            $response .= ' <a href="' . $post_permalink . '">
                              <div class="latest-news__image">
                              <img src="' . $img_url . '" alt="' . $post_title . '">
                              </div>
                              <h4>' . $post_title . '</h4>
                                <div class="post-credentials">
                                <p class="post-author">By ' . $post_author . '</p>
                                <p class="post-date">' . $post_date . '</p>
                                </div>
                          </a> ';
        endwhile;
    } else {
        $response = '';
    }

    $result = [
        'max'  => $max_pages,
        'html' => $response,
    ];

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');
```